# CakePHP White Screen of Death

Tags: cakephp

I was just merrily working on a CakePHP site and suddenly... white screen of death.  No debug information, nothing whatsoever generated by visiting the site.

Previously when this has happened there's been an error in core.php, or something else in the config folder.  But the only hazardous thing I had open at the time was core.php, and there's definitely nothing wrong with it now.

A reboot of the computer did nothing to resolve the issue.

Anyone got any ideas why else a Cake site would suddenly white-screen like this?

Comment: Are you running apache or IIS or something else as a web server? If it was IIS could there have been a MS update messing around? We had an issue with Excel files not being downloadable after an update recently (about a month ago)

Comment: Turn on errors, check the cake, php and apache logs.

Comment: No, the solution is to have some White Cake, of course.

Comment: Yep, checking the apache error logs is your friend :D

Comment: Set up version control. Right now.

Comment: I also had this problem when my core.php and database.php files were missing after pulling a new set of code from my Git repo and had those files gitignored. I guess Cake defaults to debug 0 so I had no warning. After adding and setting up my core and database everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never mind, worked it out: I'd somehow managed to drag the cake folder completely out of the application and onto my desktop.  That would do it, eh...

Comment: +1 for admitting the problem for future visitors instead of deleting/abandoning the question.

Comment: agreed, +1 for admitting the problem for future visitors!

Answer (score 3):

I had white screen when debug was 0. The handling was to clean cache folders and set debug to 1. When debug is 0 Cakephp suppresses any errors and warnings and displays nothing when an application error occurs.

- Check that debug > 0
- Clear app/tmp/cache/persistent/*
- Check local vhost error log
- Check global httpd-error log
- Restart apache, (stop, start), restart cache services (memcached ect.)
- Enter the world of `die(’stop’);` from app/webroot/index.php and downward in your application

Answer (score 2):

I spent five hours trying to solve this very problem. Nothing associated with one of my controllers would display. In the end, there were two blank lines at the bottom of my controller that caused nothing to be rendered for some reason. I removed them and everything worked again.